# Possible to load file to Javascript and directly pass it to Python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, callback

So my first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952109/visualize-an-interactive-graph) resulted in an advice of using ***javascript*** and some libraries such as probably [sytoscape](http://js.cytoscape.org/)

**The task:** to load .gspan from disk, send it to python script and convert result(netowrkx) into displayable graph back on the page, nodes of which can be clicked

**Problem:** 0 experience with web-development, therefore 2 questions:

1. Can I load this file in *gspan* without converting so I can pass it to python script?
2. Is there a way to envoke python script directly after loading the file? Like clicking one button I start loading the file, as soon as it is done - passed to python code

Any corrections of my idea of algorithm are also welcome. As I said I am new to this

Thanks!

Comment: JS and any other programming language are things that don't mix together well, because JS is executed in your browser and your browser can not communicate with Python applications/scripts on your machine. You will have to setup a Python Web Server (or are you already using one?) for this to work - unless you have control over your current Web Server and your server can execute the Python script with whatever language the server uses, e.g. PHP, node.js, ...

Comment: You could try to mix things together that can execute Javascript within Python: [PyV8] (https://github.com/flier/pyv8) , [PyQt5 webkit](https://pythonspot.com/en/pyqt5-browser/)